# Adding a bullet in a span element ONLY if there is no span element

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add a bullet to an li with the selected class if there is no span. As of now this is adding a bullet everytime the link is clicked. What is the best way to have this add and remove a bullet instead of keep adding bullets every time there is a click?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="files-list">
    <li class="selected">
        <span>•</span>
        "12-0001.hello-world.html"
    </li>
    <li>12-0002.hello-world.html</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(this).prepend($('<span />').html('&bull;')).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected').find('span').remove();
```

Comment: Why are you adding a span with a bullet instead of using css? `li.selected:before`?

Comment: If a click is the action driving the change, then there is no reason to change it to something else. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Andre good question. I should use css, maybe that would stop the duplicate bullets.

Comment: @JMack I am trying to get multiple bullets showing up. Right now if you click on the selected link, every click on that selected link adds a new bullet

Comment: I agree with @Andre. Add the bullets to the li's that have the class '.selected'. Cleaner code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check condition

```
var $this = $(this);
if( !$this.find('span').length){
   // Your code here
}
```

**Full Code**

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.find('span').length) {
        $this.prepend($('<span/>').html('&bull;'))
            .addClass('selected')
            .siblings()
            .removeClass('selected')
            .find('span').remove();
    }
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/c4tdm/)**

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try a pure CSS solution?

```
.files-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.selected {
  list-style: disc;
}
```

Then you only need to toggle the `.selected` class.

```
$('.files-list > li').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
})
```